# Safari browser stops css animation when calling new site

Tags: css, animation, safari, request

I have a link. When I am clicking on it an css-animation in a div-block should appear.
But as soon as Safari has detected that I want to go to that link he is stopping the animation and calling the site.

I also added a setTimeout() with a delay of two seconds to prove my assumption.

Animation runs for two seconds, then call the link and stops the animation.

I found nothing on the internet so for for this kind of problem. All other browsers working so far by pleasing my wish.

I know a gif would be an option, but I wanted to really make sure that my approach is not working at all. So I am asking you to be sure it's not my lack of knowledge here :-)

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 0):

In Safari when you use Keyframes you need to use the whole percentage:

this will:

```
@-webkit-keyframes keyarm {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-14deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

Don't know why but that's the way Safari works! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But my keyframe animation is working. It just stops when I click on a link with a url, you know. Then you have to wait for the next page to get loaded.

All other browsers meanwhile still continue the animation. Safari just stops at the moment I click on the link.

Any idea? :-)